# Is it possible to vertically center generated content?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Suppose I have a `div` with the following styles applied:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: relative;
}
```

To that `div` I apply a `:before` pseudo-element. The content of that pseudo-element is an image:

```css
div:before {
    content: url(someImage.png);
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The height of the `div` is dynamic. Is there any way I can vertically center the image that is part of the generated content?

Here's a [fiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/H9r5S/1/).

I can't use `line-height` since I don't know the height of the `div`. I can't use a margin or padding since the generated content has a background colour that would expand beyond the `div`. I suspect the answer is "no", but thought it might be worth asking here before I have to go and change a lot of markup!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should theoretically be possible as it's nothing more than a CSS version of a regular inline `<img>` tag, but that depends largely on its formatting (and possibly that of the generating element).

For simplicity, I would make it a background image instead, with an empty string for its content:

```css
div:before {
    content: '';
    background: #ccc url(someImage.png) center center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Notice that I'm taking advantage of the fact that you already have the gray background adequately covering the generated area — I simply center the image over that gray background.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/H9r5S/9)